# drupal 6 or 7 with ubercart

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

Have not done a drupal site in about a year, am comfortable in 6 and 7. I need an eCommerce section in the site too. Can you advise.

- Is D7 good for a live production website.
- Is ubercart more stable in v6 or v7 any potential issues
- analternative drupal based eCommerce solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have several stable sites running Ubercart with Drupal 7. The settings in ubercart with drupal 6 are a bit more straight forward, but once you get used to 7, it's not too hard to figure out.

Drupal 7 Ubercart is pretty comparable now to what Drupal 6 could offer. The only thing that is really still an issue is multiple product imports. No module or combination does it quite right. A lot of things that were controlled by modules before can be taken care of with actions.

I haven't used commerce, but my understanding is that it works a bit more like magento. If you have a white tshirt in 3 sizes, then you have 3 items with 3 skus. In D7 you can also have 3 skus but they are still contained within the same product. In commerce those 3 skus then need to be combined into a product. commerce sounds like it will be more promising for very large stores once it's a bit more stable. Ubercart will stay my go to for under 300 or so products, unless a great module is created for importing via excel.

Answer (score 0):

- Drupal 7 is your best bet these days. Most development has moved over
  to it now. If you are doing any custom development, there are a good few things to learn, but it's worth it.
- I have been hearing good things about drupalcommerce, give it a good look.

Answer (score 0):

My Experience is that D7 + commerce, is good, as long as you don't want to handle the order in the web shop, as you can with übercart.
At lease, I've not been able to get it to work, although it should be possible.
If anyone know how to achieve that funktionality, and also add track and trace numbers etc., please let me know.

übercart for D7 is good, but it lacks a module providing flexible discounts.

When I make shops I make them in D6 with übercart, due to the two problems mentioned above.
That is the only solution that has it all, that I'm aware of.
If I'm mistaken, please let me know, so I get get the shops migrated to D7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 core is beter then Drupal 6, but lot's of modules aren't compatible with Drupal 7.
If You use only ubercart module, there will be no difference.

Drupal 6 has many stable modules, and Drupal 7 not.

About alternative eCommerce: Ubercart is the best.